# What if we take the limit of the derivative of mollifier?

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f$ be a locally integrable function on a bounded open set $D$ of $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $. We know that we can approximate $f$ be a smooth function $f_{\epsilon}$ converging to $f$ pointwise as $\epsilon\rightarrow0$. We know that $f_{\epsilon}$ is defined on all subset $V$ of $D$ such that the closure of $V$ is in $D$, by taking
$\epsilon$ small enough. My question is: what if we take the limit of one of the derivatives of $f_{\epsilon}$:
$$ \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0} (\frac{\partial^{2} f_{\epsilon}}{\partial x^{2}_{j}})? $$ Does the limit exist?

Comment: How about $\sqrt{\varepsilon^2+x^2} \to |x|$? The derivative is $x/\sqrt{\varepsilon^2+x^2}$, which doesn't converge at $x=0$. One could no doubt come up with similar examples that don't converge on dense sets (the blancmange function comes to mind as a simple possibility).

Comment: While the limit won't necessarily exist, you should address *why* you would want to work with such a limit.  Perhaps the idea is to compute the derivative of a mollified function?  If so, there is a theory there (the theory of weak derivatives, and/or the theory of generalized functions or "distributions").  However, the approach is somewhat different, and comes at things from a functional analysis point of view, via the integration by parts formula.

Comment: $f_\epsilon = f \ast \varphi_\epsilon$ converges to $f$ (and the same for all the derivatives) **in the sense of distributions**, which simply means the limit $T_k = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \partial^kf_\epsilon = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  f \ast \partial^k\varphi_\epsilon$ is **not a function** but a linear functional defined by $T_k \ast \varphi_\epsilon = \partial^k f_\epsilon$.